# Symfony2 routing repeating pattern

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a URL that can accept any number of parameters but not in exactly the same order. For example

```
example.com/myapp/service1/username1/service2/username2
```

or

```
example.com/myapp/service2/username2/service1/username1
```

or

```
example.com/myapp/service7/username7
```

How can I write a rounting yml entry to catch any of those routes so that I can split them into service/username for example `array("service" => "Instagram", "username" => "JoBloggs")` or how ever many were passed to the URL.

I have access to a pre-made list of about 30 services, but usernames could pretty much be any value.

I'm not really sure even how to ask this question so I'll give any additional info that would be useful.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid something like `example.com/myapp/?service1=username1&...`

Comment: I think it is better to ask yourself why the urls can be in any order. Consistenty in URLs much better for your SEO, usabillity and your code... `"A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools." 
-Douglas Adams`

Comment: @WouterJ SEO is not required, these are temporary URL's used to demo a product.It's almost like submitting a form via a GET request, only without having to complete a form first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I can add mimic catch all at the end of a URL [Slash in parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)

```
route_name:
    pattern: /myapp/{services}
    defaults: { _controller: bundle.controller.homepage:index }
    requirements:
        services: ".+"
```

Comment: This would be your best bet. Just split the $services by "/" in your controller and figure out the key=val pairs as needed.